# Jackson TypeReference<BY ARGUMENT> JSON to Java method

Tags: java, json, function, jackson, arguments

I am trying to call a function that parse the JSON String to Java Object using the objectMapper of jackson but I have a problem.

Right now I have:

```
Batch<Person> batch = new Batch();

        //Try Map Json String "Batch" to JAVA OBJECT
        try {
            batch = objectMapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<>(){});
        .
        .
        .


//Class Batch

public class Batch<T extends  Entity> {

    public String count;
    public T[] elements; //They can be subtypes of Entities.

}

//Objects Class
public class Persona extends Entity {}
public class Dog extends Entity {}
....

//SuperClass
public abstract class Entity{}
```

And I want something like this:

```
Batch<Person> batch = new Batch();
parseFunction(Batch);
```

In the function I expect this:

```
public void parseFunction(Batch batch)
        try {
            batch = objectMapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<batch>(){});
}
```

I try to send the Batch and I get an error because the TypeReference dont know if its a Batch of Person or Batch of Dog or whatever.

How can I pass by argument the information that I need to make the TypeReference work and the map goes well?

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing `new TypeReference<Batch>(){}`? See, for example, [Map Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map) and [Jackson's ObjectMapper and TypeReference](https://northcoder.com/post/jackson-object-mapper-which-way-is/).

Comment: My problem is that I want a specific type of Batch. My Batch have a count and a [] of elements that will extends the ENTITY that is the SuperClass of "Person, Dog, etc".
The TypeRef in the first example doesnt need anything to know that is a input of Persons, but when I try to improve my code by creating the function, somehow the mapping stops working. And I dont know the right way of do it. I already saw that links, but I dont thing that fits my especific example